Insert multiple rows into a table if Count of rows in the table is 0 in sqlite
How can I insert multiple rows into a table after ensuring that the table is empty?
I found Forpas solution here but his solution explains how to insert a single row only while I need to insert more than one so how can I do that?

This question is similar to: Insert new row into table if Count of rows in table is 0 in sqlite. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Done! I edited it to be more clear.

You can insert multiple rows into a table after ensuring that the table is empty by
INSERT INTO Persons
SELECT personID, personName
FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS personID, 'Jhon' AS personName
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS personID, 'Steve' AS personName
)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Persons);


Where the "UNION ALL" statement is used to combine the result sets of two or more "SELECT" statements

One option could be to check the number of rows using HAVING clause:
--  empty table
Create Table tbl ( id Int, some_col Text );

WITH    --  some dummy data to test the insert
  data_to_be_inserted AS
    ( Select 1 as id, 'text 1' as some_col Union All 
      Select 2 as id, 'text 2' as some_col Union All 
      Select 3 as id, 'text 3' as some_col 
    )

--    S Q L : 
INSERT INTO tbl 
  Select     d.id, d.some_col
  From       data_to_be_inserted d
  Left Join  tbl t ON( 1 = 1 )
  Group By   d.id, d.some_col
  HAVING     Count(t.id) = 0

--    Check the result
Select * From tbl

R e s u l t :



id
some_col




1
text 1


2
text 2


3
text 3



WITH    -- one more dummy row to test insert with tbl not empty
  data_to_be_inserted AS
    ( Select 4 as id, 'text 4' as some_col )

--  Another insert 
INSERT INTO tbl 
  Select     d.id, d.some_col
  From       data_to_be_inserted d
  Left Join  tbl t ON( 1 = 1 )
  Group By   d.id, d.some_col
  HAVING     Count(t.id) = 0

-- Checking again
Select * From tbl

R e s u l t :   ( no rows inserted )



id
some_col




1
text 1


2
text 2


3
text 3



fiddle

